# Why the downloaded web pages have so long *.js files?

Tags: javascript, web

I am learning to develop a website.
I am the backend developer but have no experience in this web development.

I have several good references such as https://mvs.org/
In order to see how many lines of code or structure of the web pages, I downloaded the entire web page using Httrack.

I am surprised that a few *.js files include around 60,000 lines of code.
Does it mean that the web developer of the pages wrote that many codes? 
or am I missing something here?

Comment: Those big LOC counts are almost certainly due to the use of frameworks or libraries that the developer is using (such as jQuery). Most developers use code written by others in the product they are developing, since we don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Front end development implies different requirements than when one is developing on the backend.

Your context is the browser and you want to reduce the number of HTTP requests as much as possible, thus you generally bundle all your javascript files into one big file using tools such as webpack.

Your code will then be bundled with all the needed npm modules, that's why you end up with one large javascript file.

Comment: Got the point. So, the included library files are all packed up into a single file. can it be unpacked? Maybe, it should be done manually.

Comment: No it's not possible when you are viewing the source of some random websites.
If you are debugging your own website, then during development you should include source maps so you can reverse the minification/bundling process.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a library such as JQuery or React.js, which indeed can include many lines.

Sometimes (usually) all .js files are also bundled into one big file.